# Convert tile grid values from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:27700

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap, qt, zxy

Ordnance Survey have recently released an API for map tiles in the leisure series. Their tile set uses a grid based on EPSG:27700. This uses a standard zxy url

[https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy/Leisure_27700/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=foobar](https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy/Leisure_27700/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png?key=foobar)

I want to access this using a codebase that is hardcoded to EPSG:3857 tilesets. Ideally without a complete rewrite.

I am pretty sure this is not possible as they use different tile matrix sets. Is there a way to transform the 3857 call into one that will work with the Ordnance Survey data set and warp the tiles on return?

For clarity, I am attempting to modify the OSM plugin shipped with Qt Location and do not want to write a completely new plugin as this is an experimental project.

Comment: what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: Not really "software" as such more a dev environment

Comment: just wondering whether this is something that can be handled by mapproxy

Comment: I did think of a proxy but this would likely clash with the OS license terms

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? Is it possible to convert a XYZ tile request into a 27700 XYZ request. For my purpose a proxy would work.